# Override default css-class unobtrusive validation

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net-mvc, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

I created a custom remote validation attribute with unobtrusive validation and data annotations in ASP.NET MVC. The purpose of my custom attribute is to provide warnings instead of errors with an option to suppress the warnings by clicking a checkbox.
This works fine, but I am stuck on the client, when trying to style my input fields when the validation is firing. What I want to achieve is to override the default css-class(input-validation-error) with my new one "input-validation-warning", but I had no luck so far.

I tried to add the class when adding my remote method to the validator:

```
$.validator.addMethod('userdoublewarning', function (value, element, params) {
    var ignorewarnings = params['ignorewarnings'];
    if ($("#"+ignorewarnings).is(':checked'))
        return true;
    var remoteCall = $.validator.methods.remote.call(this, value, element, {
        url: "/CheckDouble",
        data: {
            email: value
        }
    });
    $.when(remoteCall).done(function(v) {
        if (v) {
            $(element).addClass("input-validation-warning");
        } else {
            $(element).removeClass("input-validation-warning");
        }
        return v;
    });
});
```

The code above only works on the initial(first) submit, but not on any later submits? I have no idea if this is a good way to do it. And I would be happy if anyone could provide some input regarding this issue.

Comment: I've never seen it done like that.

Comment: @Sparky, Ok... Could you provide some input of how to do it? The best solution would be if I could natively change "input-validation-error" to "input-validation-warning" on certain validated fields. Or some other way to style the elements when the warning attribute is doing its magic.

Comment: I wouldn't know.  I have never seen anybody try to add/remove classes from within `.addMethod()`; and I've answered nearly 700 jQuery Validate questions on SO.  Although typically, the toggling of classes is handled by the `highlight` and `unhighlight` callback functions.   From within those, you can conditionally filter which fields get which classes.  Pull the default `highlight` and `unhighlight` callbacks from the plugin and use that as your starting code.

Comment: I will try using highlight and unhighlight sparky, but I can't seem to get validator.settings? Seems like it's undefined.

Comment: I'm not an expert with the "more-trouble-than-it's-worth" `unobstrusive` plugin, but you may be better off getting rid of it and just using jQuery Validate traditionally.  After all, what's the point of `unobtrusive` once you start making these kinds of customizations.

Comment: Yes, I have gotten to a point where I probably will switch to pure jQuery Validate. Unobtrusive works great for simple out-of-box validation, but when you need to customize it simply fails in functionality. To create validation warnings in pure jQuery validate is a pretty simple customization, but in unobtrusive it's not worth it. Maybe I will try fluent validation for .NET.